# Max function not showing more than one record Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables "users" and "paymenthistory", and i want to get records of particular "user" with highest "bookingid",
But its showing only one record to me, should show 2 records,problem with "max" function,Here is my tables

Table "payment"

```
id  bookingid   userid
1   142         3       
2   146         2
3   148         3
4   154         5
```

Table "users"

```
id      name        
1       abc
2       zyd
3       xyz
4       nwd
```

Here is my query

```
$this->db->select('p.bookingId,MAX(p.bookingId) as lastBookingId,p.userid,u.name');
$this->db->from('payment p');
$this->db->join('users u','p.userid=u.id');
$this->db->where('p.user',"3");
```

Showing one record, but i want to get 2 records with same column "lastbookingid" (same),Where i am wrong ?

Comment: 'If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: With respect, it's hard to guess what you want from your query. Please [edit] your question to show your desired result set.

Comment: I don't get this you are looking for user 3 which does not have the highest bookingid what are you expecting in your output?

Comment: @P.Salmon  let me explain, suppose i have 2 records with same user but with different bookingId, so now i want to get LastBookingid(using max) for particular user( for example 3 ) , so now i expect two records with same value "LastbookingId", hope you understand my question

Answer (score 1):

I got your point from your reply in comments.
Here is the updated SQL statement that will result what you want

```
SELECT p.bookingId,
(SELECT MAX(x.bookingId) FROM payment x WHERE x.userid = p.userid) 
AS lastBookingId,
p.userid, u.name
FROM payment p
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.userid = u.id
WHERE p.userid = 3;
```

Using inner SQL statement to avoid implicitly added "group by" due to use of aggregate function (max) that causes the result to display one row only.

Here is the tested output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add **GROUPBY** clause with **max** column.

**In case of SQl please check with below query......**

```
select p.bookingId,MAX(p.bookingId) as lastBookingId,p.userid,u.name
from payment p join users u on p.userid=u.id
where p.userid=2 group by p.bookingId;
```

[please check output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxFc9.png)

Comment: Lastbooking id must be same , i wan to get Lastbooking of particular user not from all users, hope you understand my question

Comment: Selecting both bookingId and MAX(bookingId) makes no sense. Either the column is supposed to be aggregated or not; you can't have both.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id  int,bookingid int,  userid int);
insert into t values
(1  , 142   ,      3),       
(2  , 146   ,      2),
(3  , 148   ,      3),
(4  , 154   ,      5);

select t.userid,t.bookingid,s.maxbid
from t
join
(select userid, max(bookingid) maxbid ,count(*) cnt
from t
group by userid having cnt > 1
) s
on s.userid = t.userid 
where t.userid = 3 
order by t.bookingid;
```

The sub query finds the max and tests for the number of booking ids the outer query then joins.

```
+--------+-----------+--------+
| userid | bookingid | maxbid |
+--------+-----------+--------+
|      3 |       142 |    148 |
|      3 |       148 |    148 |
+--------+-----------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

@jigar-bakshi

you can try the below SQL script.

```php
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('payment p');
$this->db->join('users u','p.userid=u.id');
$this->db->where('p.user',"3");
$this->db->order_by("p.bookingId", "DESC");
$this->db->limit(2);
```

Comment: why "limit" ? , i want all records so hows your query will work ?